# Android Handheld and Wear Communication is not consistent

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-wear-data-api

We have an Android mobile app, where you can purchase parking tickets for a period. Now, we are planning to integrate it with Android wear.

What we are doing here is:

1. We want the user to get notified 15 before of the expiry of ticket.
2. To do this, we create a local notification and schedule it using Alarm Manger.
3. This scheduled notification is received by Android Broadcast receiver and display this notification on mobile device in Android notification section.
4. Further, this receiver calls the intent service to send the notification to wear.  In this step, we create googleApiClient and onConnected callback, we send the data to wear to show the notification.
5. On wear,  user can check the notification and on tap, user can extend the time of purchased ticket. This flow contains 3-4 views after notification tapping.

We have issue in step 4. Most of the time, on a very first connection (notification), wear does not show the notification and on second connection (notification), wear show both first and second notification and after that it works fine.

We tried to figure out the problem, but no success. Below is the code snippet of Receiver, Intent Service and wear side ListnerServices for understanding.

```
public class WearNotificationService extends IntentService {

private static final String TAG = "PhoneActivity";
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
public static String title;
public static String desc;
public static String data;

public WearNotificationService() {
    super("WearNotificationService");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(this, title +"--"+ desc , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
            sendNotification(title,desc,data);
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnected: " + connectionHint);
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended: " + cause);
        }
    }).addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: " + result);
        }
    }).addApi(Wearable.API).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
}

private void sendNotification(String title,String desc,String data) {
        Log.e(TAG, "i am onConnectiond: ");
        PutDataMapRequest dataMapRequest = PutDataMapRequest.create(Constants.PATH_NOTIFICATION);
        dataMapRequest.getDataMap().putDouble(Constants.NOTIFICATION_TIMESTAMP, System.currentTimeMillis());
        dataMapRequest.getDataMap().putString(Constants.KEY_TITLE, title);
        dataMapRequest.getDataMap().putString(Constants.KEY_DESC, desc);
        dataMapRequest.getDataMap().putString(Constants.KEY_DATA, data);
        PutDataRequest putDataRequest = dataMapRequest.asPutDataRequest();
        Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, putDataRequest);
}
```

}

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (null != intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (Constants.ACTION_DISMISS.equals(action)) {
            dismissNotification();
        }
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
    for (DataEvent dataEvent : dataEvents) {
        if (dataEvent.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
            if (Constants.PATH_NOTIFICATION.equals(dataEvent.getDataItem().getUri().getPath())) {
                DataMapItem dataMapItem = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(dataEvent.getDataItem());
                String title = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getString(Constants.KEY_TITLE);
                String content = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getString(Constants.KEY_DESC);
                String data = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getString(Constants.KEY_DATA);
                String id = null;
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data);
                     id = (String) obj.get("id");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                sendNotification(title, content, data,id);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void sendNotification(String title, String content, String data,String id) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, HoursExtension.class);
    Log.e("data1111", data);
    HoursExtension.data = data;
    HoursExtension.id = id;
    PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(content)
            .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
            .extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().setBackground(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.rtabg)))
            ;

    Notification notification = builder.build();

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManagerCompat.notify(Integer.parseInt(id), notification);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by sending a dummy request on app installation . Which is send once the app is installed and handled in wear by eating that first request this solved my problem . :)